# Where can I find a set of Spanish-English comparable texts? ***(Not translations)***

Tags: english, resource-request, spanish, bilingualism

This is my very first post, I hope I'm making myself clear.

What I'm asking for is a set of texts that are equivalent in both languages in terms of difficulty, word frequency and register (i.e. two news articles that talk about a similar topic with the previous controlled factors). I'm not entirely sure but I think they're called *comparable corpora*.

We're carrying a set of experiments with Spanish-English bilinguals and I need these texts so the participants can activate their language mode before the start of the experimental tasks.

Comment: Wikipedia articles are often not translations.

Answer (score 2):

The starting point for a corpus search is the [Virtual Language Observatory](https://vlo.clarin.eu) by the European CLARIN ERIC. Entering the words `English Spanish comparable corpus` in the search slit gives [nine results](https://vlo.clarin.eu/?q=English%20Spanish%20comparable%20corpus), among them [EuroParl-UdS](https://hdl.handle.net/21.11119/0000-0000-D5ED-5).

Answer (score 1):

Try here: [Menu of free parallel texts Spanish English](http://learn-spanish-with-bilingual-stories.weebly.com/menu-of-free-parallel-texts-spanish-english.html). (But these texts would not be as carefully controlled as you asked.)